# record locking with PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do the following.

- Lock a row in the Users table for USER ID 10
- SELECT the number of credits the User has
- Update the number of credits the user has
- Release the lock

How do I lock specific table rows using PHP and MYSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the InnoDB engine you can use row locking by starting and committing a transaction as described in the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-lock-modes.html
See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html

Comment: So you are saying that once you start a transaction, the mysql table rows referred in the transaction are locked until the transaction ends?

Comment: Just read the manual (especially the first link), it is all explained very well there

Comment: The first link above is now forwarded to: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html 
It has great information about the types of locks, I was previously using SHARE MODE and have now changed to EXCLUSIVE LOCK. However the page is missing details about how to release locks.  
The simple answer is to wrap the lock and the insert / update in a transaction.  A lock is released when the transaction is committed or rolled back.